# R Plotting Series of Data with Secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a data frame with 4 columns:

```
Quarters <-  c("Q1","Q2","Q3")
Series1 <- c("1%","2%","3%")
Series2 <- c("4%","5%","6%")
Series3 <- c("1000","2000","3000")

df <- data.frame(Quarters,Series1,Series2,Series3)
```

Quarters as x-axis, Series1 & Series2 as left y-axis, Series3 as right y-axis and a legend.

I have seen some solutions with ggplot using scale_y_continues, but then the secondary (y) axis has to be a multiple of the primary axis.  Which I do not want, as the data will be dynamic and the ratio might not hold through in all instances.

Any solutions how I might go about creating this?  Perhaps ggplot is not the way to go?

Comment: You can add a secondary axis that is a transformation of the primary axis with `sec_axis`:  http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html 
But ggplot is philosophically opposed to multiple unrelated axes, so if that's *really* what you want you're going to have to look elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about ggplot2, but you can use `par(new = T)` in R to plot a graph on top of another one.
If you remove the right axis from the first plot and add it manually on the second one it should look good.

```
Quarters <-  c(1,2,3)
Series1 <- c(0.01,0.02,0.03)
Series2 <- c(0.04,0.05,0.06)
Series3 <- c(1000,2000,3000)

par(mar = c(5,5,2,5)) # Leaves some space for the second axis

plot(Quarters,Series1,type="l",ylim=c(0,0.1))
lines(Quarters,Series2,col="red")

par(new=T)
plot(Quarters,Series3,type="l",axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA,col="blue") # Removes axis and labels so they don't overlap
axis(side = 4) # Adds secondary axis
```

Does this work for you? More info [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-single-plot-with-two-different-y-axes/)

Comment: Yes, this definitely answers my question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot2` is perfectly fine and deals with dual-axis very well. You would use `sec.axis` within `scale_y_continuous` or `scale_y_discrete` (or really just about any valid `scale_y_`) call:

```
  scale_y_continuous(
    "Casualties* due to:",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~. *0.001, 
                        name="Aircraft passengers carried, bn", 
                        labels = scaleFUN, 
                        breaks = seq(0,3, by=0.5)),
    limits = c(0,3000),
    breaks = seq(0,3000, by=500),
    labels = comma
  )
```

The following creates two axis, one with a break of 0 to 3000, by 500. That's the axis on the left (primary axis). The second one goes by 0 to 3 by 0.5, but there's no reason why it should follow that scale. You can very well have scales that are not multiples of the primary axis.

You can get a plot like the following:
[image]

Using the above technique. If it is helpful I put up the full `ggplot` code to recreate the above plot [in this post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-elegant-plot-you-have-made-using-ggplot2-in-R-Embed-the-code-if-possible/answer/Samuel-Chan-3?share=c4d2604d&srid=pOyd). Completely done in `ggplot2` including the horizontal legend and secondary axis.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. Although @Fino has given me what I was looking for, I have to admit ggplot2 is a lot snappier.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct: the [discrete axes](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.2.1/topics/scale_x_discrete) do not support the `sec.axis` attribute!